# Creating a :remote=>true post using AJAX rather than rails 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

I've spent a day spinning my wheels trying to understand how Rails :remote=>true works. The question below seems complicated but I'm trying to understand this simple question with the information I provide:

**How can I make an Ajax call that simply renders as JS without using :remote=>true?** 
**From my understanding :remote=>true simply generates and handles an AJAX call:**

My view looks like this:

- opts in a very complicated way, creates a link with :remote => true. This is omitted for simplicity

> ```
> .e_list
>   = opts.sort_link(:name)
>   = opts.sort_link(:description)
>   - e_list.each do |e|
>     .entry
>       = link_to(e.name, '#', class: 'select_e', data: {e_id: e.id})
>       = e.description
>   = paginate e_list, remote: true, params: {search:"j", com_id: com.id}
> ```

Gallery.js.erb

```
$('#com<%= @com.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render(partial: "shared/com", locals: {com: @com}) %>');
```

My Controller:

```
  def gallery

    if params[:com_id] 
      @com = @s.com.find(params[:com_id])
      @com.filter = params
    end

    if c = @s.com.where(:_type => "Com").first
      @current_e = c.entries(@user.app_id).first
      @current_e.og_url = view_context.og_url(@current_e)
    end

    render :text => "foobar" if !@current_e

  end
```

logs, after the user clicks on the pagination links or sort links (the key is those links have :remote => true)

```
Started GET "super long url" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-04 16:08:42 -0700
Processing by CController#gallery as JS
```

**SO I TRY TO RECREATE THIS WITH AJAX:**

```
  $('button.search').live 'click', (e) ->
    search = $(e.target).attr('search-term')
    success_callback = (results) ->
      if results
        console.log(results)
        update_components(results[0].entry, '.entry')
      else
    $.ajax(
      url: 'super long url that is exactly the same url as above!'
    ).done ->
    return false
```

**MY FAILED RESPONSE THAT DOES NOT RENDER AS JS, YET I THOUGHT :remote => true was simply an ajax call wtf?:**

```
Started GET "super long url identical as the one that renders JS" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-04 16:07:22 -0700
Processing by ContestController#gallery as */*
```

What is going on? How can I make an Ajax call that simply renders as JS without using :remote=>true?

Comment: nope. Started GET "/screens/4fa02763dc1c82269c0001da/contest/gallery?app_row_id=5&component_id=4f9f0305dc1c8255a300006c&page_id=136755716356584&screen_only=1&screen_permanent_id=4f9edb0cdc1c8228800000ef&search=j&source_component_id=4fa0228edc1c82269c00012c" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-04 16:07:22 -0700
Processing by ContestController#gallery as */*

Each url is very long, but identical.

Comment: try `/screens/4fa02763dc1c82269c0001da/contest/gallery.js?app_row_id=5...`. If you want the js from the response to execute in the browser you should need to do something like `eval(response)`, but i'm just suggesting, I never done it and even know how to eval code of a string in javascript.

Comment: ... if you submit this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: done, I'm glad I could help. it was the `.js` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`/screens/4fa02763dc1c82269c0001da/contest/gallery.js?app_row_id=5....`

If you want the js from the response to execute in the browser you should need to do something like eval(response), but i'm just suggesting, I never done it and even know how to eval code of a string in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    dataType: 'script'
})
```

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
/* your jquery file */
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

...
$('#button').click(function() {
  $.post('/controller/action', {
    query_string1: value1
  });
});
```